# PyopenSSL and scrapy install fails in Python 27, Win 64 Bit

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, pyopenssl

My package install (using PIP & Easyinstall) fails every time when I install `PyopenSSL` and `Scrapy` on **Python 2.7. OS: Win 8.1 64 Bit**.

The error details are below:

C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tcbuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release_openssl.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release_openssl.obj _openssl.c
build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release_openssl.c(429) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory error: command 'C:\Users\Suraj\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

**Exception information:**
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 211, in main
 status = self.run(options, args)
 File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 311, in run
 root=options.root_path,
 File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 646, in install Kwargs
 File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 852, in install
 show_stdout=False,
 File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 733, in call_subprocess
 % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command "c:\python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\suraj\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-ajzmpr\\cryptography\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\suraj\appdata\local\temp\pip-kppgmc-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\suraj\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-ajzmpr\cryptography.

**Troubleshooting done so far:**

1.The error is same with Easyinstall and Pip
2. Changed the logs to Verbose levels.
3.Checked multiple Stackoverflow links, still no luck:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951303/fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-openssl-opensslv-h

**Installed programs on Windows**

Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable (x86) - 11.0.61030 Microsoft Corporation   07/10/2014  17.3 MB 11.0.61030.0

Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Package for Python 2.7 Microsoft Corporation   26/07/2016  380 MB  9.0.1.30729

Thanks in advance

Comment: [`cryptography` recommends using `pip`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#on-windows). Make sure you install the wheel package, use a recent pip, and probably use `--no-cache-dir` and `--only-binary`

Comment: Thanks for your response Paul, I am trying Pip install <Package Name>, in this case : PyopenSSL & scapy.

Comment: Use `pip install --no-cache-dir --only-binary cryptography` (it will install PyOpenSSL dependency), and then `pip install scrapy`

Comment: Thanks Paul.. This is what worked in my case 
pip install --only-binary :all  cryptography 
and then pip install scrapy.

Comment: Your timely response is highly appreciated.

Comment: bad formatting, https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help will help

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue. Here is what i did:

Install Cryptography first on your computer, using the following link: https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#on-windows

if you don't have openSSL installed on your computer the above page will have the link for that. Add the environment variables as mentioned in the link and try to install it again.

Comment: Hi Anmol, this is what worked in my case: --only-binary :all cryptography (followed by..) 
pip install scrapy

Comment: great! i did not have OpenSSL on my computer so had to install that too!