# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I am trying install paramiko on windows 7. Below error is seen every time:

```
C:\Users\achayapa\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for     Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tcbuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\_openssl.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\_openssl.obj
_openssl.c    build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\_openssl.c(433) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory

error: command 'C:\\Users\\achayapa\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\achayapa\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-lhlycd\\cryptography\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\achayapa\appdata\local\temp\pip-t1xtw1-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\achayapa\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-lhlycd\cryptography
```

Tried solutions mentioned in below links:

[Fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951303/fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-openssl-opensslv-h?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[PyopenSSL and scrapy install fails in Python 27, Win 64 Bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38625492/pyopenssl-and-scrapy-install-fails-in-python-27-win-64-bit)

Installed below programs already on windows:

Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable (x86)
Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler Package for Python 2.7 Microsoft Corporation

Answer (score 0):

On Centos, I encountered the same problem. This fixed it: `sudo yum install openssl-devel` - but on windows I don't know the analogous command. It cannot find your openssl library C headers, so either you need to modify your python search path, or move files into your search path.